# Google Docs publishing 'server'

Tags: automation, google-docs

You might be familiar with Google Docs' (and presumably also the other 'office' apps) ability to communicate with a blog server to publish a post directly from its interface. (It's located in Share > Publish as a web page).

I'm interested in knowing the standard for the data transmission that this system uses. Of course, I can always reverse-engineer the code for one of the blog applications supported, but a formal specification would be more useful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to support three types of API :

- [Blogger API](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/blogger/)
- [MovableType API](http://www.sixapart.com/developers/xmlrpc/movable_type_api/)
- and [MetawebBlog API](http://www.metaweblogapi.com/)

Those (at the the two last ones) seem to be based upon some kind of [XML-RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC) protocol ([see also](http://www.xmlrpc.com/)) ; so, the ability to use them has to be linked to what API (classes/methods) they export -- for blogging-software, those will be methods to get/create posts, most probably ; and only a few methods, I guess, so that using those API is not too complicated...

The first one seems to use some kind of ATOM-based format (see, for instance, what has to be used to [create a new post](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/blogger/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#CreatingEntries))

Still, using that kind of "half-standard" API means you'll have to code some stuff each time you want your application to support a new API ; happily, there are not **that many** blogging-software related APIs : many blogging software tend to use the same ones, which is great : it allows you (or google docs, btw ;-) ) to publish to many different kind of software with only implementing the 2 or 3 most important / most used APIs.

For instance, the well-know platform [Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) supports both Metaweb, Blogger, and MovableType APIs -- even if those were created for other software, at first -- coincidence (or not ^^ ) those are the same as Google Docs supports : the most used, I suppose ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the Blogger API that Google Docs uses is the original (depricated) [XML-RPC one](http://www.blogger.com/developers/api/1_docs/), not the new GData API. The original Blogger protocol is the oldest and the simplest of the three supported (good for a quick implementation).